# What is the best way to sum bit sets/bit strings in java

Tags: java, performance, addition, bit, bitset

Assume I has several series of 0s and 1s. I need to add the values at all the same indices in different Strings

```
110111111111000101111111110000000001111011000111110  
000000000000011001001000011111000110111100000000011  
111111000100011001001000011111000110111100000000001
000110000000011001001000011111000110000000000000010
111111000100011001001000011111000110111100001111111
```

The result will be like

```
3324............................................243
```

What would be the best way to do it?

The length of a bit string is approx. 200 and all have the same length.

The data is in `String[] arr`, each element of array has one set of 0's and 1's i.e `arr[0] = 110111111111000101111111110000000001111011000111110` so on...

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Are you looking to interpret those bit strings as big integers, and sum those?  I'm not aware of any other "sum of bit strings".

Comment: @JonathonReinhart - No. The OP just has several series of 0s and 1s. He needs to add the values at  the *same* indices in different Strings.

Comment: @TheLostMind Ah. I would certainly recommend spaces in the notation of the expected result. Otherwise, there is a huge ambiguity; what if there is a total of more than nine 1's in a given index?

Comment: Also, you haven't told us in what format you have this data. Is is in a file? In memory as a bitmap spanning a byte array? As an array of bools? The answer would vary depending on how you can access the data.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I can put them in an array or put space in between or anything not causing ambiguity is okay. But I'm looking for something better than bruteforce

Comment: @JonathonReinhart - I was wondering about the same thing.. 2 nested for loops ought to do it in `O(n*m)`.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of input strings is less then 10 you could do it like this.

```
String[] input = {"110111111111000101111111110000000001111011000111110",
    "000000000000011001001000011111000110111100000000011",
    "111111000100011001001000011111000110111100000000001",
    "000110000000011001001000011111000110000000000000010",
    "111111000100011001001000011111000110111100001111111"};
int[] counters = new int[input[0].length()];

for (String s : input) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == '1') {
            counters[i]++;
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < counters.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(counters[i]);
}
```

Comment: If you say `System.out.print(counters[i]+"-");`, it will work for more than 10 strings but this is `O(n*m)`